# Multi language website in magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.2.1, internationalization

I want a language switcher in Magento header to Arabic language. But unfortunately there is no Arabic language extension available so I created  store in Arabic language and added pages in Arabic language. But I want to know what I will do for top links and Magento static text in each page.

Answer (score 2):

What I find easier then the Translate Inline is to make a translate.csv in

`app/design/frontend/theme/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

Where the languagecode matches your preferences ofcourse. In this csv you can translate each string per line like so:

`"Original string in Magento", "Translated string in Magento"`

like (example in Dutch):

`"Add to bag", "Toevoegen aan winkelwagen"`

The results are the same as with Translate Inline, but more user-friendly. You do have to make sure to get the original string completely, case-sensitive. If a string doesn't translate, it's because it isn't wrapped in a `<?php _e('Translatable string'); ?>` tag (if this is the case, the string wouldn't be editable using Translate Inline).

One of the advantages of doing it via a CSV is that you have a centralized overview of all translations, per language, and you can edit it without having to turn on Translate Inline for your specific IP adress and such.

Answer (score 1):

You should create arabic store view rather than store, if you want to share the information between the store views. If you wish to change the top links and static content magento provides translate inline tool. Go to

> system->configuration->developer->translate inline

Enable for front end then go to frontend and you will see a book like icon click there and popup will come then translate the words, don't forget to select the store view.

If you wish to translate the category names you can do it in admin panel by selecting specific store view for category then uncheck use defeult value option and fill the translated text in the name :)

Comment: @Savin If That Worked for you, you can accept the answer :)